# Не работает прыжок у гугл динозаврика

Tags: javascript, html, css

не работает, прыжок

```
const dino = document.getElementById('dino');
const cactus = document.getElementById('cactus');

document.addEventListener("keydown", function(event){
    jump();
});

function jump(){
    if(dino.classList != 'jump'){
        dino.classList.add('jump')
    }
    setTimeout(function(){
        dino.classList.remove('jump')
    },300)
}
```

Comment: Что именно не работает и как это проявляется? В консоли есть ошибки? Как минимум, у вас проверка странна `if(dino.classList != 'jump')`, замените ее на `if(!dino.classList.contains('jump'))`

Comment: или classList на className

Comment: В консоли нет ошибки, проблема в том что у меня прописана анимация на классе jump и при нажатии кнопки она не проигрывается